# Why my profile looks for /usr/local/etc/profile.global (NIS)

Tags: ssh, bash, login, nis, bashrc

My Ubuntu ID is manged by NIS/yellowpage. For some reason, when I log in, I'm getting this message.

```
cat@local:~$ ssh catserver
cat@catserver's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 15.10 (GNU/Linux 4.2.0-25-generic x86_64)

Last login: Thu Apr 21 11:46:22 2016 from x.x.x.x
-bash: can't find configuration file /usr/local/etc/profile.global; exiting.
Connection to catserver closed.
```

If I create an empty `/usr/local/etc/profile.global` file on this server, then it works.

But I don't understand why my bash scripts try to load this file. I searched these files: `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc`. And none of them does have code to load `profile.global`.

How can I fix this problem? Is this my bash profile problem or some NIS problem?

Comment: Does your system have any files under `/etc/profile.d/`?

Comment: Yes, `appmenu-qt5.sh`,  `bash_completion.sh`, and `vte.sh`. I cat'ed `bash_completion.sh` but can't find a clue. This happens all our servers. So, probably a problem in NIS?

Comment: What about the `appmenu-qt5.sh` or `vte.sh` files?

Comment: `profile.global` doesn't seem to be documented anywhere as a standard configuration file. Have you tried looking for `profile.global` inside files in /etc? (e.g. `find /etc -type f -exec grep profile.global "{}" \; -print`, or maybe also `grep profile.global /{usr/{local/,},}{s,}bin/*`)